# Como mudar parâmetro de uma função na url com Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Gostaria de saber se tem a possibilidade de mudar um parametro da url com codeigniter. tenho uma função criada chamada editar e nela eu passo o id do cliente a ser editado, só que no lugar do id que é o parametro, gostaria que fosse mostrado o nome do cliente, existe essa possibilidade?

Segue código para analise:

```
public function editar($id)
{   
        $data                = array();
        $data['NOMECLIENTE'] = '';
        $data['IDCLIENTE']   = '';

    $cliente = $this->ClienteM->get(array('id_cliente' => $id), TRUE);

    if ($cliente) {
        $data['IDCLIENTE']   = $cliente->id_cliente;
        $data['NOMECLIENTE'] = $cliente->nome_cliente;
    } 

    setURL($data,'cliente');

    $this->parser->parse('painel/cliente_form', $data);
}
```

Comment: Sua dúvida não está clara. De onde vem esse método `setURL`? Vc quer que o nome apareça onde? No link ou como atributo do link?

Comment: Olá ShutUpMagda o método setUrl e um helper criado para definir algumas ações como listar e salvar, quero que o nome apareça na url no lugar do parametro id

Comment: como o link de editar esta sendo gerado?

Comment: O código que vc postou não faz o que vc descreve. O que esse código faz é preencher um `array` e carregar uma `view` com base no `$id` enviado via `$_GET`. É possível que esses links estejam sendo gerados com `setURL`, mas vc não mostra o que ela faz, então fica difícil ajudar. Além de mostrar a função, vc devia colocar um exemplo de como a URI está ficando e de como quer que ela fique. Afinal, qual é o motivo de substituir o id na URI?

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer o que você pede: acessar a URL informado um ID mas ser redirecionado para outra que contém o nome do cliente na URL (não entendo qual a vantajem disto). O que não é possível é acessar diretamente a URL que só contém o nome do cliente (imagine o caso de 2 clientes com mesmo nome, qual seria o acessado? Você preciso identificá-los pelo ID).

O que acontece é que você será direcionado para outro método do controle que irá desprezar o segundo parâmetro, o nome do cliente. De uma maneira bem rápida *e feia*, ao receber o parâmetro $id da URL, você obtém o dado do nome, e repassa para um segundo método, que usuárá apenas o $id, como o primeiro, mas mostrará também o nome na URL.

Assim:

```
public function editar($id) {   
    // Esse 1° método não faz nada, só obtem o nome do cliente e redireciona
    // para o método editar2 (que contém o nome do cliente na URL)
    // e ele sim faz o que precisa fazer
    $id = intval($id); // Sanitize sempre
    $cliente = $this->ClienteM->get(array('id_cliente' => $id), TRUE);

    if ($cliente){
        // Coloquei __CLASS__ aqui por que não sei qual é o nome da classe
        redirect(__CLASS__.'/editar2/'.$id.'/'.$cliente->nome_cliente);    
    } 
    else {
        // Cliente não localizado, tratar...
    }   
}

public function editar2($id, $nome_cliente) {
    // Aqui faz o serviço de verdade, mas agora está exibindo
    // o nome do cliente na URL

    // AQUI ESTÁ A IMPLEMENTAÇÃO VERDADEIRA DO MÉTODO...
}
```